# Can we call functions in #if statement?

Tags: c, if-statement, c-preprocessor

Is this possible in C?

```
#if functionA() < functionB() 
    //... 
#endif
```

Comment: `#if` is not a statement, it is a preprocessor directive. Preprocessor directives are processed before functions are defined, so no.

Answer (score 8):

Only if `functionA` and `functionB` are macros rather than functions.

Answer (score 0):

The #if statement is a preprocessor statement, code functions aren't available (but [macros](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Macros.html) are).

[C Programming](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/cpreprocessor.html) provides a good simple overview of the C preprocessor usages.

Answer (score 0):

If `functionA` and `functionB` expand *at compile time* to integer constants, then they can be compared. The only way this can happen is if they're macros, not functions, as dan04 explains. More details can be found in [the gcc documentation for `#if`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/DeveloperTools/gcc-4.2.1/cpp/If.html#If), which is generally applicable no matter what compiler or platform you're using.

Answer (score 0):

No we cannot call a function as condition to `#if` directive. The condition in `#if` needs to to be a constant expression only.